# Equation with vectors.

Tags: vector-analysis

> Let $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ be unit vectors separated by an angle of $\pi/4$. Solve the equation for $\vec{u}$: 
>   $$
> \left(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{u} \right) \vec{b} + 4\vec{a} = 2\vec{u}.
> $$

I' am trying for about three hours but I can't find the solution. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you please update the question with some ideas you have thought of when you tried the problem?

Comment: Yes. I was trying using "Law of cosines" because we now that the big angle of the two vectors is 135 degrees.

Comment: @JoeFomotiyos Do you know dot product, You have received all the hints to solve the problem, let try and show your result.

Comment: I found u = 2a + (8+2sqr(2))b/7. Right?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Write $\vec u = s\vec a + t\vec b$ and rewrite the given equation. Since $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are non-parallel, if $s\vec a + t\vec b = s'\vec a + t'\vec b$, then we must have $s=s'$ and $t=t'$.

Comment: We haven't learnt vector equations with derivatives yet. Sorry. Is there any other way?

Comment: @JoeFomotiyos Those are not derivatives! they are parameters.

Comment: Thanks! Understood

Comment: I found u = 2a + (8+2sqr(2))b/7. Right?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that $a \cdot b = b \cdot a = \cos (\pi/4) = \sqrt{2}/2$. If we dot your equation with $a$ we get
$$
(a\cdot u)(b \cdot a) + 4 = 2 u \cdot a
$$
so you can solve for $u \cdot a$. Similarly you can dot with $b$ and solve for $u \cdot b$....

Answer (score 1):

If you use $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ as a basis and write $u=x\vec{a}+y\vec{b}$ then you have $(x+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}})\vec{b}+4\vec{a}=2x\vec{a}+2y\vec{b}$. So $x=2$ and $y$ is immediately found too.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have $\vec u=t\vec a + s\vec b$ that is

$$2\vec u=2t\vec a + 2s\vec b=\left(t+s\frac{\sqrt 2}2\right) \vec{b} + 4\vec{a}$$

thus

- $2t=4$
- $2s=t+s\frac{\sqrt 2}2$

from which we can find $t$ and $s$.

Comment: yes I tried to set x=a(vector)u(vector) but it didn't help

Comment: @JoeFomotiyos I think that we can find $\vec u$ in terms of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ thus the idea is to find the projection of $\vec u$ on $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.

Comment: I found u = 2a + (8+2sqr(2))b/7. Right?

Comment: @JoeFomotiyos $s$ should be simply $2+sqrt 2$ then $u=2a+(2+sqrt 2)b$, let check directly on the original equation if it works